# Yii2 andFilterWhere with CASES. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, activerecord, yii, filter, yii2

I have a query with ActiveRecord with an if condition:

```
    $query = Contacts::find()
        ->select([
            'c.*',
            'cg.contact_group_name as groupName',
            'if(cg.contact_group_name = "advertiser", ad.fiscal_name, ap.fiscal_name) as relatedName'])
        ->from('adv_contacts c')
        ->joinWith('contactsGroup')
        ->joinWith('advertiser')
        ->joinWith('publisher');
```

This means if users contactGroup is advertiser i get value from one table, if publisher from another... This works fine..

But now I have a problem with Filters.. How to tell the Filter:

```
IF cg.contact_group_name = "advertiser", filter from ad.fiscal_name, else ap.fiscal_name.
```

Maybe I need to use cases? But can you use cases in andFilterWhere?? I cant find any tutorial for that... Or maybe there is another way?

Currently I have this filter:

```
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'or',
        ['like', 'ap.fiscal_name', $this->relatedName],
        ['like', 'ad.fiscal_name', $this->relatedName],
    ]);
```

But this is ofcourse bad, because it always returns all values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CASE WHEN for Yii2 operator format is not documented http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#operator-format
but if you like you could use  $query->andWhere with  string format  .. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#string-format

with the foresight to explicitly check if the values are null before invoking the andwhere function (...)

```
if ( $this->your_balue <> NULL) {
   $query->andWhere('CASE WHEN  .... THEN .. ELSE .. END');

}
```